# What does x ∈ {0, 1}* mean?

Tags: notation

I was reviewing some papers and came across the notation x ∈ {0, 1}*

I want to know what it means. Thank you!

Edit: I noticed I did not put enough context to the question. The paper I reviewed was about blocks in a blockchain. It states:

"A block is a triple of the form B = (s, x, ctr), where s ∈ {0, 1} ᵏ, x ∈ {0, 1}* and ctr∈N"

I hope this gives more context to the notation. Sorry for the incomplete question before!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be more specific about the area of mathematics that this paper is in. That said, my guess would be that the star is the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

Comment: It looks like $x$ is a binary string made out of digits (letters) $0$ and $1$ and a string $x$ can be empty (indicated by the star). Is the context binary algebra?

Comment: Can you please cite some of these papers?  It is common in mathematics for the same notation to mean many things, depending on context---without knowing the context in which you are seeing this notation, it is impossible to know what it means.

Comment: In information theory papers, $\{0,1 \}^*$ means the set of all sequences made up of $0$s and $1$s.

Comment: @ironX To be precise, all such *finite* sequences